# Can't start "Glory Of The Dead"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The characters (The Huntress lady and such) are just standing around the dead silver hand after I've returned from collecting the witches' heads for Kodlak. The remaining Companions that are outside will talk when activated but only repeat the same garbage while the companions inside the building won't talk as it says that the character is busy.

I haven't a clue what to do. I read somewhere that you need all the fragments of a blade or sword, but I believe I must have already completed this mission to access the quest I'm currently stuck on.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Directly from the [Skyrim Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glory_of_the_Dead):

> A glitch occurs where this quest does not start after completing Purity of Revenge, even though Vilkas mentions the funeral. On the PC version the fix to start the quest is by using "**setstage C06 0**" on the command console.

Hopefully you're on PC and can fix this :)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, and it was driving me crazy! I could not get Glory of the Dead to start. No one was at the Skyforge, there was no funeral at all. All the companions acted as if it was just a normal day. Even Vilkas, after telling me to go to Skyforge for the funeral, just slowly walked back up to Jorrvaskr and stood around like an idiot. I had tried going back to several different saves, and did setstage commands at those different saves, but nothing would activate this quest.

Finally, I managed to get it to work, and here's how I did it: After finishing off the Silver Hands and retrieving the stolen fragments of Wuuthrad, I fast traveled to Whiterun with Vilkas like I had done several times before. Vilkas then tells me that Kodlak's funeral must be prepared by now, and that I should meet everyone up at Skyforge. So, the glitch continues as usual. Purity of Revenge is marked as completed, and Vilkas goes walking away back up to Jorrvaskr. I walk up to Skyforge, no funeral. I then proceed to wait at the Skyforge until the next night, since it was already about 6 am, and I believe the Funeral is supposed to take place at night. So, I use the Wait function and fast forward to about 7 PM, then I used the setstage command: "**setstage C06 1**".

Immediately, Glory Of The Dead was initiated and all the Companions were gathered at the Skyforge in front of me for the funeral. I really hope this helps those of you who have this same problem and are having trouble finding the answer like I did. Good luck!